# Getting Select Options from Database, doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project where I get an error, and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to get entries from a MySQL table to put into a dropdown.

```
<?php
          require("../script/connect.php");
          $query = "SELECT Brands.BID, Brands.BName FROM Brands ORDER BY Brands.BName ASC";

          $result = mysql_query($query);
          echo "<select name='brands'>";
          while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) != null)
          {
            echo "<option value = '{$row['BID']}'>";
            echo "{$row['BName']}</option>";
          }
          echo "</select>";
          require("../script/disconnect.php");
?>
```

There are 3 `Brands` in the database and I'm getting 3 dropdown options, all giving back the same error.

```
Notice:  Undefined index: BID in /opt/lampp/htdocs/nis_obkm/pages/enter_Product.php on line 24
```

So in my dropdown field, I can choose one of the three options titled with the notice above.

Connect and disconnect works fine in my PHP scripts!

Any ideas?

Comment: BID is not in your database table.

Comment: check case of table and column name also

Comment: BID is in the Dbase table ;)

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: Problem Solved! Thank You! If I use $mysql_fetch_assoc()$, everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

The array you're getting back is indexed numerically and you're trying to reference string keys. Change [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) to [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc).

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer correct if you've found it helpful.